# Swift Eureka SelectableSection baseValue doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I have this code for `Eureka` library:

```
    let section = SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>("Section:", selectionType: .MultipleSelection)
    section.tag = "section"
    for obj in arrList {
        section <<< ImageCheckRow<String>(obj.name){ row in
            row.title = obj.name
            row.selectableValue = obj.name
            row.baseValue = obj.id
            row.value = nil
        }
    }
```

this shows selectable list, but next code doensn't work as it should:

```
@IBAction func saveAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let section = self.form.sectionByTag("section") as? SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>
    for obj in section!.selectedRows() {
        print(obj.baseValue)
    }
}
```

this prints `name` field, but needs to print `id`(`row.baseValue = obj.id`).

Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been reviewing your code and I found this , seems that if we use `SelectableSection` we need to use `selectableValue` instead of `baseValue` for our proposes, but I think that this is an bug from `Eureka` because `selectableValue` and `baseValue` are the same although we set different values

you can mitigate this using `row.selectableValue = obj.id` instead of `row.selectableValue = obj.name`

### Edited

try this for `Int` values in `selectableValue` replace

`<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>` for `<ImageCheckRow<Int>, Int>`

also replace `section <<< ImageCheckRow<String>(obj.name)` for `section <<< ImageCheckRow<Int>(obj.name)`

and finally adjust saveAction as I do

```
@IBAction func saveAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let section = self.form.sectionByTag("section") as? SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<Int>, Int>
    for obj in section!.selectedRows() {
        print(obj.baseValue)
    }
}
```

this works for me with Int on selectableValue

The problem is this

```
public final class ImageCheckRow<T: Equatable>: Row<T, ImageCheckCell<T>>, SelectableRowType, RowType {
    public var selectableValue: T?
    required public init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        displayValueFor = nil
    }
}
```

the `selectableValue` is of type  a pattern for any type you pass in declaration that is why `<ImageCheckRow<Int>, Int>` resolve the problem with `Int`

I hope this helps you, regards

Comment: It doesn't allow `Int` in `selectableValue`.